# Get last PrimaryKey created in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

I have a table in mysql, with primaryKey, Auto Increment and Not Null, when i create a entry with PHP, the primary key os autogenerated, how i can get it with PHP?
I thinked to do `$SQL = "SELECT MAX($id) FROM ".$my_table;`
but the problem is, if two users make the request almost at the same time, the last record could change.
Another solution is to use `START TRANSACTION`, but o dont know how to use exactly in PHP.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: if you want to keep an order you should work with transaction, how ever remember if you lock a table only 1 user at the time will be able to make a request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php):

```
mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO blah VALUES('superblah');");
$newid = mysqli_insert_id($link);
```

Just request the `mysqli_insert_id` after you run the query to return the new ID. Piece of cake.

Comment: I dont think they ever specified they were using mysqli but its pretty much the same commands just without the "i" at the end.

Comment: if they're not using mysqli, they absolutely should be. mysql_* commands are now deprecated.